# Javascript Textfield Input Regex Change BG Color Freezes

Tags: javascript

I have a text field with the ID `chat_msg_box` which is for a chat room which has a private message feature.

It's easy to mix up the command (the internal command to send a private chat message) so this script looks for the input `/msg Username>>` and turns the background text field color to a light grey.

That part worked out fine but I realized I needed to change it back to `#ffffff` for when the user sends the text or if they change their mind and delete it. Once I put in the `else` statement, it all screws up.

That's why the code below includes a second `if` statement instead because I've been trying different ways to accomplish the task. No matter what, when I load the page I try to type and nothing enters; it freezes. If I switch to another screen and back it returns and everything I tried to type enters into the box. It then works as intended.

Without an else, else if or second if statement this works (but not what I fully need).

```
regex = /\/msg\s[a-zA-Z\s_-]+>>/  // All characters allowed for username.
var textInputElement = document.getElementById('chat_msg_box');
textInputElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var text = textInputElement.value;
    if (regex.test(text)) {
        document.getElementById('chat_msg_box').style.background = "#d2d2d2";
    }
    if (!regex.test(text)){
        document.getElementById('chat_msg_box').style.background = "#ffffff";
    }
});
```

Comment: The code seems correct and working (in Chrome). Any specific browser you are having issue with?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works on Chrome for me as well (I just tried). The problem I'm having is with Firefox 78.9 which is for Linux. It's the most updated version and I just updated it today. I don't think Firefox Linux versions equate to the Windows one's but can't be sure. The thing is... this is a SIMPLE script so I don't understand what the problem is. Does anyone know why this is happening or can offer any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be affecting Firefox browser.

Here's what happens:

1. page starts with empty input
2. one character is pressed
3. `keyup` handler is called which changes `style.background = "#ffffff"`
4. for some reason Firefox applies the styling incorrectly and text becomes covered with white background (invisible)
5. clicking outside the input element reveals the text that was entered.

This is an issue with setting `background` and in how Firefox applies it. I'll see if I can reproduce and report a bug to Mozilla.

I was able to get it working cross-browser by changing `style.background` to `style.backgroundColor`.

```js
regex = /\/msg\s[a-zA-Z\s_-]+>>/  // All characters allowed for username.
var textInputElement = document.getElementById('chat_msg_box');
textInputElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var text = textInputElement.value;
    if (regex.test(text)) {
        document.getElementById('chat_msg_box').style.backgroundColor = "#d2d2d2";
    }
    if (!regex.test(text)){
        document.getElementById('chat_msg_box').style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="chat_msg_box">
```